Puzzle regarding service panel and home circuit modernization
The home was built in the year 1970. We bought it in 2003.
Here's the panel:

For more detailed pictures see full panel plus some top wiring, full panel only, section of ground/neutral bar, close-up of 100 A service wires into panel, and exterior service meter and disconnect.
The external meter is shown in the bottom-center inset. The other pictures provide details about the service panel inside the home opposite to the external electrical service meter and service cutoff. There is no separate ground and neutral strip. It's just the single strip seen in the middle -- the ground and neutral are not wired separately and then starred together. Ground and neutral cannot be isolated at the panel.
Nothing about this meets code. Not even old code, let alone anything close to the NFPA 70 from 2020 (which I have on hand.) This means that kitchen lighting is tied into wall outlets, upstairs rooms are tied together with downstairs rooms, bathrooms coupled together with hallways, and so on. You get the idea. It's a mess. And there's no compound AFCI (parallel and series protection) anywhere to be seen.
This is a 200 A service and we are the only home on the transformer. The transformer is exactly rated for 24 kW and the service technician involved in its replacement with a new transformer, last year, told me that's what it should be: 100 A each for L1 and L2.
Our panel, when we bought the place in 2003, had 50 A at 240 V for the oil heater, 40 A at 240 V for the stove, 40 A at 240 V for the dryer, two subsections on this panel (that can be seen above) each of which are given 60 A at 240 V, and one subpanel feeds underground to a barn with its own subpanel rated for 60 A at 240 V. Both hot water heaters, with 30 A at 240 V each, sit on the same 60 A subpanel (the middle one in the picture at left or next-left.)
Since there's no main breaker all I can definitely say is that I have a total maximum of 310 A at 240 V on the top subpanel section shown above, where the external service L1 and L2 wires enter the home. And there's no single mains breaker to enforce the 100 A each for L1 and L2. That simply doesn't exist.
Turns out, about half a year ago, the service provider had to dig out their neutral from the transformer to our home and replace a section of it that was literally eaten away, turned into white aluminum powder. I'm not entirely certain it was only because of age. It may have been the growing use over time, too.
I have spoken with several licensed electrical contractors, and one of the County's senior electrical inspectors, and appropriate engineers at the service provider. I can get a service disconnect at the drop of a hat. I just call up the service provider and ask. They will be out within a working day's time to do it. The reconnect is quite the opposite. This requires the county inspectors and the service provider's inspectors and a sign-off by a licensed electrician who certifies the inside of our panel and also our home circuits.
We have six adults and three children on-site. I can't just move everyone out of here.
I'm at a bit of a loss and struggling to come up with a workable plan. The licensed electricians that visited here weren't able to come up with a way to make this work for them, and their business model, and also something that would work for us, both at the same time.
At this time, the only thing I can see is to work within the household to clear out one small section of the home at a time, a room or two, and perform the work in pieces that way, bringing the new wiring to a nearby metal box, temporarily. Eventually, given enough time we could get all that brought back to the entrance panel location (or another one that the service provider may now prefer) and once the home's duplicate work is sufficiently prepared, take a few days to shut everything down and bring together the new wiring, disconnecting the old. This might be some years out, though.
If there are intermediate or alternate constructive thoughts to suggest, I'd like to know. Even some way to engage in a more productive discussion with licensed contractors?
Update

Photo of electrical panel inside cover
Stove/Oven unit: 8.4 kW
Dryer: 7.1 kW
Central oil heat and blower motor (5000 sq ft home): 10 kW est.
Water heater #1: 5.5 kW
Water heater #2: 4.8 kW
Miscellaneous electric space heaters: 7x1800 = 12.6 kW
Four freezers, 3 full sized refrigerator/freezers: 0.5-1.0 kW avg
Last year's actual electrical usage report -- during that year we did not use the oil heater.

The central oil heater blower motor isn't accessible at this time. But the 50 A breaker suggests more than 40 A, when operating. And for now, I have to go with that as an estimate. I do recall talking with the oil heater consultant a year ago who told me that the motor we have is from 1970 and is very inefficient and should be replaced if we keep the oil heat. So far, that's all I have to go on.
As can be seen from the chart, the average usage on the highest month is more than 34 A on L1 and L2, both. This is about 1/3rd the maximum service. And it is an average value across an entire month. Obviously, the peak will be higher than the average.
Thanks
To manassehkatz and Harper and ThreePhaseEel my profound thanks. Every single thought has been helpful in shaping thoughts towards the future. Not just short-term, but also long-term, as well as options that should be considered and provided for even if, in the end, they are not used.
It's also helped me understand more, by being forced to lock down more details. For example, I hadn't realized that my pumphouse motor is actually a 3-phase unit. It makes sense, given it's size. And a controller board was added by the pump service company to tie the existing split-phase to the 3-phase motor. This will feed into further discussions with the PGE representative, who (it turns out) was selected by his boss for his creative thinking and willingness to really explore the options for us. We are considering a 7.2 kV installation, now, with a class A1 room that PGE will have access to. And they are suggesting the idea of running a special line to our home from the substation (about a mile away) that will guarantee continuous power even when the power lines are down. (They have substation generators on-site for critical applications -- and we may meet their requirements.)
This has been a huge help in so many ways. I just want to offer my profound thanks for every thought, every question, etc. It isn't a small thing. You are each in my mind and have my deepest thanks for every word offered to me.
I wish I could pay it back. But perhaps I can pay it forward to others, once I get through this planning process and start down that road.
Thanks, again!

Oil heat uses 12 kW???? That sounds very high.

What exactly is your question or concern? You haven’t identified anything that was obviously a code violation when built.

Also it would be helpful if you could take a new version of the “full panel” photo with all the breaker text/numbers legible.

700W per fridge/freezer is simply not plausible. You’d be paying nearly $10,000 a year in electricity just for those. That may be the peak when the compressor starts, which takes only a second or two. Actual average fridge draw is more like 100W.

@nobody I'm still going through your edits. As far as the refrigerators go, refer here. 100 W is far too little. I know they use more than that. But I'll have to attach a meter to them for a day to be sure.

I have power meters on my two fridge/freezers. The indoor one averages 80W continuous / 700kWh per year. The one in the garage is 100W / 876kWh per year. They’re nothing fancy, 10-15 years old. If yours are really that bad, you’d likely see a positive return on investment (by replacing them with more efficient units) in as little as a single year.

I picked the first refrigerator that came up when I searched on Home Depot 25.6 cubic feet, side-by-side, so a decent type but nothing super fancy. Govt. EnergyStar label says $91 per year, 647 kWh/year, estimated. That works out to 647,000/(24*365) = 74 Watts average. That's pretty darn close to nobody's 80W continuous (=average). And about 11% of 700W.

The electrical usage report is just giving you monthly totals and average temps. So it gives you average (January = almost 6,000 kWh, so ~ 8 kW average, = ~ 34A) but you really need not monthly or even daily but ideally 15-minute readings or at least hourly to get a handle on peak demand.

@manassehkatz Thanks for pressing me on the frig/freezer. One of the ones I have is listed as an average of 580 kWhr/yr so that fits with your 70 watt figure. I'm going to go get the figures for all the units I have here. The unit I have has a 365 Watt "defrost mode" and is nameplated as 7.1 A. That may be a peak figure for the unit, not sure. In the meantime, I'm adjusting that figure in my question. I stand corrected -- and I apologize for not putting more time into that figure before writing. It's clear to me now that this is a small, inconsequential number in the larger scheme of things.

@manassehkatz For load calcs though, do I use the namplate's 115 VAC, 7.1 A for the frig/freezer? Or its average rating on the energy star website? Seems to me I should use the nameplated value. Which is quite a bit more than the value one would get from energy star.

I'm not sure that refrigerators/freezers even normally enter into the Load Calc - they may get rolled into the general values. In any case they aren't a big factor because they are not that large and run very intermittently.

My measured usage on two refrigerators, a 2014 and a 2002 - work out to 100W when running and average 41W. These are not super deluxe models with vertical compartments and crud through the door, those cost efficiency.

You've got a lot of different issues here. I think the best solution, overall, is a full panel replacement with as big a panel as you can get - e.g., a 42 space panel. That panel would include a main breaker (more below about that), eliminating your Rule-of-6 current mess. The other issues (circuits shared between different parts of the house) may or may not actually be issues, depending on whether they were allowed in 1970 - a lot has changed since 1970.
For what its worth, I didn't have nearly that level of mess, but I did have a relatively complicated change with my heavy-up 2 years ago. I had 2 1950s fuse boxes (yes, fuses not breakers) plus a small breaker panel from my kitchen redo in 2000. Rule-of-6 really bad - pulls needed in each box to get everything off, which is worse than your "turn off the top 6 breakers" situation. But my electrician was really good and we (I was his helper for a lot of it - fun stuff!) managed to get everything switched over with individual circuits down for an hour or two here and there but full power shutoff only for a few hours on 2 different days (one at the beginning of the process, one near the end). What I am saying is this can be done.
A few things to consider:
Meter Main
Depending on your state and/or county adoption of NEC and local variances, you may need an outside disconnect. That is normally done with a "meter main" - basically a small panel in a big box together with the meter socket. That provides an easy emergency disconnect for firefighters. If you need to install a meter main (which your county can tell you), you need to check with the utility on the specifics (because some utilities are extremely picky about the types they approve). A meter main becomes the true main panel - i.e., neutral and ground bonded there and totally separate everywhere else. However, your replacement big panel is still your practical main panel, with the exception that neutral and ground have to be separate.
If you have a meter main then that gets a main breaker specified by your utility. If 24 kW is a hard limit then that means a 100A main breaker. If they can push it to a larger number (e.g., transformer replacement or it turns out there is some wiggle room) then that determines your main breaker. But your inside big panel can then have any size main breaker, so the typical bundled 200A breaker is just fine as it is a switch but not for protection.
If you don't have a meter main then your inside panel is a true main panel and the rules above (100A if 24 kW, etc.) will determine the main breaker size in that panel. If you are limited to 100A, do NOT think "I must find a panel with a 100A main breaker" - you don't need to do that. And in fact, if you do that you will likely find you can't get a 40 or 42 space panel. You get a big panel and then replace the main breaker with a smaller one if necessary.
Big Inside Panel (whether technically Main or not)
This new panel (40 or 42 spaces) will get rid of your Rule-of-6 mess, allow for full neutral and ground bars (they must provide enough space for all possible neutral and ground wires, though sometimes you have to add extra ground bars to do that) and provide room for future expansion or splitting of circuits (e.g., separate bathrooms from other rooms).
The key here, as I found out, is to work this as follows:

Physically install the new panel, ideally within a few feet of the old panel. Note that one key code item you need to watch for is working space - 30" wide by 36" deep - which needs to be empty space in front of the new panel. No plumbing, fixtures, appliances, furniture, etc. This will start out as a subpanel.
Run as large a feed as practical from the old panel to the new panel. Depending on what spaces are available, this will probably be between 30A and 60A, with appropriate sized cable. One possibility in your case is to see if you can temporarily use one of the top 6 breakers (1 is feeding the bottom of the panel, the other 5 are feeding subpanels or large 240V loads) to feed the new panel. If that breaker is less than 60A, replace it with a 60A breaker (assuming those are readily available at a reasonable price) and then move the original load of that breaker to the new panel. With an hour (maybe less) of downtime on that one breaker's original load, you are now ready to start moving almost everything else.
Move each circuit from the lower portion of the old panel to the new panel. One at a time. Each circuit will only be down for a little while, so people can work around it (upstairs bathrooms will be dark for 30 minutes, use the downstairs; refrigerator will be off for an hour, don't open it until that circuit is back on; etc.)
Work on as much as possible of the outdoor work (meter main if needed), running new feeder through the wall (if needed), etc. before getting the utility to pull the meter.
Call the utility to pull the meter.
Work as fast as possible to get the rest done - moving the remaining Rule-of-6 circuits, install the new meter main (if needed), etc. If planned well, this should be a process of a few hours.
HERE IS THE KEY My utility, but I suspect most, will not consider the job totally done until necessary inspections (utility and/or county). But they will allow a licensed electrician to reconnect the meter so you have power. Then once the inspection(s) is(are) done, they will do any final work (e.g., move the feeder from old meter socket to new meter main, details vary).

Inspection
This is potentially a big issue. It may be worth getting the county (not an electrician - they are alternately lazy or looking to increase the work $$$) inspector to take a look and tell you what code changes are actually required. For example:

Meter Main/Disconnect - required if that is current code for your area, otherwise it is optional
AFCI - generally not required on existing circuits - this is a big deal as it gets very expensive as it can only be done (practically) with AFCI/breakers.
GFCI - generally not required on existing circuits - this is a big deal for 240V circuits, which often require GFCI in current code. For 120V circuits (kitchen, bathrooms, etc.) it is not a big deal and I highly recommend putting in GFCI, especially for kitchen and bathrooms as the cost is actually quite low with GFCI/receptacles (as opposed to GFCI/breakers).
Circuits shared between bathrooms and other rooms - not allowed in current code but with a 1970 house almost certainly grandfathered

What is NOT going to be grandfathered is incorrect wire - e.g., 14 AWG on a 20A circuit, grounds where they should have been in place originally (which is almost certainly the case for 1970) and some other things. A panel replacement does NOT normally require getting the circuits up to current code, but they do need to be up the standards for when they were originally installed.
Load Calculation
310A by breaker handle numbers on a 100A service means nothing. What really counts is an NEC Load Calculation. Get one done. If you squeak by under 100A, don't worry about it. If you are between 100A and 200A then talk to your utility about what can be done. If you are over 200A then some serious work needs to be done.
But in addition to a Load Calculation usually being far lower than "add up breaker handles", it is also often more than your actual usage. It can be a bit hard to figure out your actual usage, but your utility might provide that either in your bill or online - look for "peak demand". It is quite possible that your peak demand is close enough to 100A that you did OK with the transformer. But that may not be good enough long-term and a Load Calculation is the gold standard.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Fixing the Panel
The classical maneuver to deal with a situation like yours is essentially a two-step plan:

Add a grounding bar to the existing panel and move all the existing equipment grounding wires to it.  In your case, you'll need to use a NOS Siemens ECLX072M or 073M kit for the bar itself, and if your panel doesn't provide suitable mounting points, you'll need to use a pair of Garvin GSST self-drilling grounding screws to attach the bar to the panel cabinet.
Replace the Meter with a Meter/Main.  You'll need to use an EUSERC-compliant 200A meter-main or meter-panel with feed-through lugs for this; a Siemens MC0816B1200ESN fits the bill, as it provides an auxiliary 50A disconnect that, while not completely conformant with the current 230.71 requirements, is useful for providing critical power during future work.  (The EST version of this part does fully conform with Code, although it's not as available as the ESN version, and means you won't have that spare disconnect position to draw critical power from while you're working on the panel.  The Square-D CU816F200PS is also a suitable solution for this problem, albeit again not as available as the Siemens part listed above.  It does have the advantage that it can use a fused AC disconnect and a SRKUGMM kit to supply an auxiliary service tap in a Code-compliant manner, though.)  This, of course, will require that the bonding screw be removed from the old main panel at this point.  It may also require a 4 wire SER cable to run from the meter location to the panel location, but it looks like this should be possible, and if the meter-to-panel run was originally done in metal conduit, it won't be necessary either.

However, while this is the most practical route to getting out of a jam like yours as it means all the rest of the work can happen pretty much at your leisure, it'll still require some serious conversation between you, your utility, and your AHJ at permitting time to understand that the scope of inspection at this point must be limited to the scope of work done, instead of being a comprehensive Code inspection of the house.  (Basically, you need to get them to understand that "perfect is the enemy of good" here -- you can't simply take a month's vacation while the house is redone in a single go, and while knowledge of other Code issues with the current system is valuable, it's not something that can be actioned as a condition of turning the power back on, given your circumstances.)
On Load Calculations
I ran a load calculation for your existing house, by the way, and without the oil system in play, you're a hair over the limits for a 200A service (I came up with 49.4 kVA used vs 48 kVA available).  However, since you're replacing both the space heaters and the oil system with a heat pump, there's no need to go through the extra gyrations involved with a Class 320 upgrade, as there isn't a whole lot of inexpensive Class 320 meter/main hardware that's legal under the current codes on service disconnects.
Note that with the new appliances mentioned below, you have enough headroom to squeeze a sizable EV charger in on the service, although you may need to have it on the load shed box if you want it to be usable during power outages, depending on the size of your generator and inverter.  Even if you keep the bad old hot water heater and dryer, going to a cold-climate heat pump without emergency heat is sufficient to get you within 200A service limits.
Issues with the Long Term Plan
Your first problem: distillates don't keep like they used to
Back in the bad old days, most folks didn't worry about diesel going bad -- it doesn't form gums and varnishes the way gasoline is prone to, and the sulfur and fused/branched aromatic content was high enough to keep microbial growth at bay.  However, for good reasons (making our planet not rain lead-acid battery leakage, among others), modern diesel has far less sulfur and aromatics in it than it used to, meaning that you need to turn it over every 6 to 12 months and regularly use biocide additives (Biobor being one of the more common ones) to prevent microbes from growing at any water/fuel interfaces in the tank.
Kerosene and jet fuel are generally not as extreme on this, which means they can be stored for somewhat longer, (typically two to three years), but will eventually suffer from similar issues with microbial growth due to water in the tank if they are not turned over on a regular basis.  Furthermore, while exercising a generator does consume some fuel, a generator of the size envisioned, somewhere in the 20-30kW range given what you're dealing with, will burn all of 18 gallons of fuel per year exercising for 15 minutes at the equivalent of 1/4 load every week.
As a result, without an oil burner to turn the tank over every winter, you're pretty much stuck with a giant, oily paperweight on your current plan.  As a result, I'd seriously be considering alternatives to a diesel generator were I in your shoes, as buried propane tanks aren't an environmental hazard if they leak (just a fire one, which can be dealt with by locating the tank and generator well away from the house and in a readily defensible area), and propane has absolutely no difficulties with shelf-life, unlike diesel.  Furthermore, burning kerosene or jet fuel in a diesel engine violates EPA clean air regulations in 40 CFR 60.4207, unless you somehow have a batch of kerosene or jet fuel that's been desulfurized to 15ppm w/w, that is.
On the topic of solar...
The other major power source that'll be in play for you is solar, barring anything completely dealbreaking, like being completely shaded by the hill you're on, not just trees.  This is because while the image of a house snuggled into the trees looks like the ultimate in bucolic cottagecore, it is also a serious fire hazard when set in a pyrophilic forest environment, such as those typical of the American Southeast and West Coast.
Instead, proper wildland-urban interface practice creates a buffer zone of defensible space, cleared of brush, trees, stockpiles, and other fire-prone landscaping, for a good 100 feet or more around the house.  This, in turn, creates enough non-shaded area around the house that you should be able to get at least some insolation on a set of rooftop panels.
Of course, there are other renewable sources one could tap, such as wind or any micro-hydro opportunities that are available on-property.  However, most of these are treated as inverter-based resources similar to a solar panel, so I'm going to limit the discussion to solar for simplicity's sake.
As to what sort of solar system you can put in, you'll need some form of module level power electronics, either "optimizers" like Tigo's, or a straight-up microinverter system with AC coupling.  This is because while you can probably get some insolation, you aren't going to be in optimal solar conditions most of the time, so you need to milk as much performance as you can get out of a partly shaded array, and traditional string inverters just can't do that without help.
And now we get to batteries
The good news is that battery storage is far more practical than it was, with a variety of vendors offering setups in multiple chemistries (traditional Li-Ion oxide cathode cells, the much more docile LiFePO4/LFP cells, and even lithium-titanate-oxide, which has the potential to be even kinder than LFP is).  However, even with LFP and putting the batteries in the garage, you're still limited to 80kWh of storage before you get into heavy-duty fire suppression requirements.
While this isn't bad at all, as it should get you anywhere from 2 to 4 days of autonomy from a full charge without fuel consumption or solar harvest, it's still far short of being a sole-source solution.  (There are a few vendors that claim systems like that are possible, but the current fire codes haven't caught up with them.)
So, I'd recommend an 80kWh battery setup along with whatever you do for generator or solar.  This can be an "AC battery" in the style of the Powerwall when combined with the appropriate gateway device, or an open-architecture 48V DC battery feeding a set of multimode inverters such as Outback Radians or Victron Quattros.  The latter requires more hardware due to battery circuit protection requirements, but offers a much wider range of vendors than integrated AC batteries do.
In any case, you'll be looking at about 15-25kW of battery inverter capacity, depending on what inverter vendor you use and how much load you're willing to have actively managed by a load-shedding system during power outages.  (Ideally, the well pump, HVAC, and range would all be load-sheddable, letting you run off at most two inverters.  We'll get to more of that in a bit though.)
Note that while one can build up BESS out to 30kW of inverter nameplate capacity (and beyond), Portland General's service rules set a hard cap of 25kW on the inverter capacity of residential storage systems.    They also require that a lockable, visible-open (safety switch) disconnect be present at the point of coupling where the ESS interfaces to stuff that's purely utility-powered.  (This is the same limit and disconnect requirement that they impose on net-metered residential solar systems, so this disconnect will do double duty to cover that.)
Meet your new appliances, not the same as your old appliances!
Along with the battery and solar work, we'll need to go through your appliances and replace them with much, much more efficient models.  First, your heat pump will need to be an inverter unit, most likely a cold-climate mini-split but some cold-climate inverter HPs are available in the traditional split system form factor as well.  My very preliminary "plug and chug" sizing calculations using a calculator I found online peg your house at somewhere between 3 and 5 tons of HVAC load, but you will want to have a professional Manual J load calculation run in order to specify your new heat pump properly.
If you can manage it, putting the heat pump on a load shed controller can also be helpful to limit the size of generator and inverter system needed. This will require a more sophisticated load shedding system than the crude one for the well pump described below, but does have the advantage that you can put other large loads on it, like your range, and anything you might want for EV charging for that matter (although if you can work the integration, proper EVEMS, such as what the Wallbox Pulsar has, might be better than a bang-bang shedder for this).
Second, those two hot water heaters will both get removed and replaced with a single Sanden/ECO2Systems 83-gallon split-system heat pump water heater.  This monster of a unit has a nearly 120 gallon first hour rating despite only using just over 1.5kW of power, and doesn't suffer from the "spike" issues under high demand that are known to happen with hybrid heat pump heaters, where they are forced to revert to plain old electric operation to keep up with the load.
Finally, we also swap your dryer out, for a LG heat pump dryer (why the LG? it's both a large-capacity unit, and one of the most efficient ones on the market).  This does slow down your dryer cycle some, and is a bit fiddlier to keep clean than a typical dryer in some ways, but lets you ditch the dryer vent atop being much more power and energy efficient than a regular dryer, and also has the advantage that there just isn't anything in a heat pump dryer that reaches the autoignition temperature of lint during normal operation, reducing the risk of lint fires.
(You could also get an induction range or cooktop at this point, but that's not strictly necessary.  It would let you get rid of the homebrewed keypad lock on your range, though, as it's pretty hard to start a fire with an induction cooktop.)
Dealing with that well pump
The other barrel of fun we have is the well pump.  Like the battery situation, putting in a large enough water tank (tens of thousands of gallons) in to hold you over for a multi-week power outage without some other source of help would be extremely costly.  However, we can get you into a decent position with some trickery.
This requires:

A direct burial suitable potable water tank/cistern, with anywhere from 1500 to 5000 gallons capacity.  This gets buried in the hillside at least 150' above your house's roofline.
Three pipes of the same type as your existing water line.  One of them runs from the existing well connection up to the tank, and two run back down from the tank to the well.  The trick here is that one of them is drawing from at least 500 gallons up in the tank, preferably 750 to 1000 gallons if you are using a large enough tank, and this will be your domestic water supply.  The other connects to the bottom of the tank, to provide water for fire protection.  This ensures that there's enough reserve water in the system to meet structural fire protection requirements even if the pump becomes inoperable or you run out of fuel.  (That'll be the topic of the next section.)
A pair of 5 kVA single phase encapsulated transformers.
A 600V, 30A Class J fuse block with a 10A time delay Class J fuse in it.
A suitably long length of 1/0-1/0-2 aluminum URD triplex to get from the main house to the pumphouse.  (You can safely shrink this if the run length permits you to not exceed 5% voltage drop on smaller wire.)
A pair of industrial fiber IO extenders (a W&T 17633 set works for this, although you'll need to find 12-24VDC at each end to run them on).
A suitably long length of direct burial rated multimode optical fiber, terminated to match the fiber IO extenders. (one will live at the main house, the other at the pumphouse)
If you don't have some other load-shed facility, then two or four adjustable, split-core current switches capable of 125A and wired in an ORing configuration.  These will go around the wires coming into the standby panel busbars. (The seemingly "extra" two sensors account for the possibility you might want to have a generator interlock on your standby panel so you can manually bypass the inverters for repairs.)
An appropriate control and sensing scheme for the pump, as well as a float or altitude valve for tank fill control.  (This can be done with conventional pressure sensing provided the tank fill valve is reliable and configured correctly.)
A neutral bar or distribution block that can accept an EGC and a GEC tap, as well as the 1/0 and 2AWG Al wires in the pump standby feed.
Some insulated mechanical splices capable of range-taking from 14AWG out to at least 1/0 AWG to make various connections at the transformers.
A "spa panel" box with a 2-pole 20A breaker to go at the pumphouse and provide a place to make bonding and grounding connections for the pumphouse transformer, as well as providing secondary overcurrent protection to the transformer there.
And a 100A transfer switch that's capable of transferring power without the aid of external help and also doesn't rely on a source neutral for controls.  (Generac switches won't work for this, for instance, because they're dumb bricks that need a Generac generator to drive them around.)

The basic idea here is that the fiber link is used to push a load shed signal to the VFD at the pumphouse, which can read it on a discrete input and shut down the well pump if current draw on the standby system exceeds limits and the transfer switch is on "generator" (really, standby system) power (the generator start output from the transfer switch can be used to indicate switch position).  The standby feeder to the pumphouse is run at 480VAC using the transformers and Class J fuseblock; the latter is small enough it should be able to fit into the wiring compartment of a 5kVA transformer with room to spare for the rest of the wiring.  The transfer switch, then, selects between utility power from the pumphouse/shop transformer and standby power from the main house standby system; this works out because it's only powering the VFD/pump combination, which has no use for neutral and thus doesn't receive one.  (The transfer switch doesn't receive neutral either.)
As to that fire suppression thing...
Last but not least, we get to that old bugbear: fire.  While people in rural areas generally think of wildfire as the primary fire threat, and this is dealt with by way of good forest management (sending Smokey out to clean up the trash before it becomes a target-rich environment for fire) and defensible space, structural fire is still a serious problem in your situation, especially given that you have inhabitants who are not going to have an easy time evacuating.
As a result, with a multi-thousand-gallon cistern on the hillside basically giving you your own personal water tower, we can parlay that into the fastest way to get wet stuff on red stuff that money can buy: fire sprinkler protection.  That 500-1000 gallon reserve I mentioned earlier is enough to get you 10 to 20 minutes of firefighting water for a NFPA 13D 2-head worst case load, and with 65 PSI of hydraulic head available at the peak of the house's roofline to overcome friction loss, you shouldn't have trouble getting the pressures and flows needed to run a standalone NFPA 13D fire sprinkler system that can mean the difference between a literal mop-up job and a multi-fatality tragedy.
Note that you'll want to use a double check valve assembly at the house (where you can keep an eye on it) with chained and padlocked shutoffs to protect the tank contents from backflow, as well as having a test-and-drain at the system low point and a 1.5" fire department connection available on the outside of the house.  (Your local fire department will likely want to know about the cistern as well, in case they need to grab some water from it to fight a nearby flareup.)
Note also that this does not cover the fire suppression requirements for a large (>80kWh) ESS, which default to a 0.3 gpm/ft^2 extra hazard density (IFC 1207.5.5 point 1) provided the system is divided up into physically separated banks not exceeding 50kWh each.  (For comparison, residential fire sprinklers lay down about 0.05gpm/ft^2, and the sprinkler system in a large office building operates at about 0.1gpm/ft^2.)  You'd need a system whose UL 9540A large scale test results permit an installation with reduced fire suppression to put more than 80kWh in a single space.
(It might be possible to split the system up so you have 80kWh inside the garage, 80kWh on an outside wall or in a shed near the house, and 40kWh in a utility closet within the house, putting you at 200kWh of total storage.  This would require an AHJ signoff and either integrated AC batteries or a split-inverter setup where different inverters manage different battery banks.  The latter might be the way to go anyway as it reduces the need for heavy cabling and distribution hardware, but I have my doubts about how well it would balance loading across the different batteries...)

On your new appliances, there's a Technology Connections for that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zheQKmAT_a0

There's no doubt this is a panel in which the asshats have been hard at work.  But it still seems like a dirty panel moreso than a broken panel, and the code violation that most concerns me is 90.1 if I'm honest.  Let's start at the source.
The transformer is not your problem
NEC is not concerned with stuff on the utility side of the weatherhead.  The 24 kVA transformer is a big bag of Not Your Problem. You get to rely on the service size which the utility proffered to you.  If they say it's 200A (48 kVA or 200A on both wires, then that's what it is.
For your information, that's covered by a different book called NESC (please do not buy a copy) and they are allowed to significantly, even dramatically oversubscribe equipment.  Not least, a pole pig that is 1000 lbs of metal and oil has a very different thermal rise characteristic than a bus stab in free air 1/16” wide.  And by the way, that's also why peak usage data from the utility is useless. They care about peaks that run long enough to overheat the transformer.  That's too long.
From data on this transformer, you flowed the idea that you have 100A service. Delete that idea.
Service is sized by a formula
The service, purportedly 200A or 48 kVA, needs to not be overloaded. Now that 200A breakers are under $2000, we use a 200A main breaker for that, but back in the age of split-bus panels, breakers over 60A were not affordable.  So in that type of service, you hang it ALL on the Load Calculation i.e. NEC 220.82.
Sacramento's form is most faithfully to the intent of 220.82 in my opinion.  Your list of subpanels sounds terrifying, but the panels don't count, only the loads. And the 310A sum of breakers in the main-breaker area doesn't bother me at all, you'd need to see what the Load Calc says.
Subpanels don't count in the Load Calculation, so you could just keep going with subpanels as long as the Load Calc works.  If you do EVs, make sure you do EVEMS.
You list quite a few portable plug-in loads.  (Not fixed-in-place). Those don't count.  Those are covered by the catch-alls on lines 1-3 on Sacramento's worksheet.  I certainly hope you are not using portable space heaters as primary heating, they are not certified and unsafe and illegal to run unattended.  If you need to do that, install cold-climate heat pumps, or if utility cost is no object, Cadet baseboards,  however those then will count since they are fixed in place. The heat pumps will eliminate the old A/C.
Cleaning up that panel
I know you have a lot of animus toward that panel, and far be it from me to separate an electrician from his boat payment, but I think it's dirty not broken. I'm not loving the split-bus Rule of Six no main breaker thing, but there are cheaper ways to solve that.
That is a classic Murray panel (I recognize the curvy breaker catches) and takes MP breakers, now redesignated Siemens QP.  All alien breakers not MP or QP need to be replaced before they damage a bus stab.
To start with, the neutral bar is overstuffed and you need to install some accessory ground bars and move grounds to them, and re-organize the neutral bar so every neutral is solo.   Siemens accessory ground bars may screw right in to predrilled sites in the panel (no doubt obscured by wires right now), or you can always drill/tap new sites. If the screws are -32 thread pitch and #8-#10, that is legal as an electrical path to the case and no jumper wire is needed.   That will clean up the neutral bar.
Your panel is grandfathered and doesn't need AFCIs, but if you want them, actually, you are in luck. Siemens makes a tandem AFCI. For real, no joke.  Wow, that was easy, I wrote out a whole thing about adding a subpanel.  Subpanels have no effect on the Load Calculation, remember.  If you choose a Siemens subpanel, this is also a good time to think about generator interlocks since Siemens supports their panels very well with interlocks.  That and just wire grooming to clean up the aesthetics.  No wire cutting. Don't do that dumb thing where people cut the wires as short as possible.  That's unnecessary. And don't bundle wires.
Resolving Rule of Six
Now, what to do about that Rule of Six business? As long as your Load Calculation checks out, you're legal.  If you have plans for EV charging, read NEC 2023 625.42(A) and use dynamic load management, easy peasy.
But what I would aim for is, once the panel is fit and won't offend electricians, is insert a "ranch panel" aka "trailer panel" right after the meter.  This is a panel with 1 main breaker, 8 breaker spaces, and thru lugs onward to the next panel.  Will that make your indoor panel a subpanel? No, because of NEC 230.85, and you can even put some things out there, per 230.82.   That's a very contained job that you should be able to get an electrician to do in coordination with the utility in a day.  Of course most will want to quote a new indoor panel because hey, easy $4000 in billables, but you just tell them "thanks for the quote".
Thoughts on grid-down survivability in 2024
On water, my first thought is if your well is 150' below your house, is there anywhere on your property 60' above your house? Because the "easy peasy" way to resolve the well pump is have a huge tank 60' above your house. (2 feet for every 1 PSI you want). Your house is plumbed ONLY from the tank, and the pump ONLY replenishes the tank.  Thus, pick your tank size. 2 ways to replenish: get a generator to the pump, or have a water truck refill the tank.  The pump can also be a "dump load" used to burn off excess solar.
I realize right now it's all about the generator howling 24x7 as the source of all power.  But radical gains in battery technology, plus PG&E evilness, are starting to paint a different picture.
Increasingly, the win is a whole-house battery system fed by solar, simply because it diminishes the dependence on PG&E and their wackadoodle electricity prices. Then, the generator serves a different role: it only needs to replenish the battery "tank", so it doesn't need to be capable of carrying house peak loads, and this monster doesn't need to be spinning 24x7 just to keep the refrigerator alive. It can be run at a time of your choosing and only needs to cover the gap solar did not.

Thanks for providing more info. I had figured that split-phase 200 A was 48 kVA. But they said they wouldn't give me such a transformer and I, as you wrote, decided that they "knew their business better than I" and that I needed to adjust my view about it. I'm glad to hear your opinion. Also, I need to read your additions, too. And I've just made a formal request for a consultation with PGE. Last time they were here, I asked them to walk the property and examine all the various underground services here. They could not see a way to provide power underground after reviewing the situation.

Ultimately, I need batteries, diesel/jet fuel generator (I refuse to use gasoline or propane for safety reasons), tear out oil and replace with central heat pump air-exchange types using modern 2024 refrigerants, and ensure that I can survive a month without access to power. (We've already experienced 2 week stretches and power outages here are frequent enough.)

@periblepsis -- I take it that even an entirely-outdoor propane system is out of the question? (i.e. a system where the tank, lines, and generator are all out in the yard, with no propane lines running into buildings)

@periblepsis -- Also, does your water come from a well, and is an energy (air sealing and insulation) retrofit of the house an option?

@ThreePhaseEel Yes, propane no matter its location is completely out. This has been a long discussion here and we cannot re-open that can of worms. For our safety (we have forest fire risks to worry about, jet fuel is safe to move, handle, store, etc.) highly flammable options are off the table. It's a joint agreement that cannot be altered. Of course, we might be open to new forms -- RTG based on Pu239, for example. ;) But the hydrocarbon issue has been settled. Water comes from a 320 ft deep well and is pumped to the home, 150 feet above, using about 150 PSI at the pump to get 70 PSI here.

@periblepsis -- how many HP is the well pump? and noted re: propane (wasn't sure what was ruling that out, whether it was some sort of safety concern with the kid vs. issues with tanks in wildfire)  also: is the energy retrofit on the table, or is that base already covered? (would go well with the heat pump stuff if it hasn't been addressed already)

@ThreePhaseEel The well pump was moved to its own transformer before we bought the place. I think it was 1993 when that happened. (We have two transformers on the property.) The well transformer is located at the well and it also powers a separate nearby shop. I don't know the HP, but the pump was just replaced a little over a year ago when we rebuilt the structure for it. (Here's a picture after I'd torn down the old structure and started a new one. The new pump was added later by a contractor we use.)

@periblepsis -- one more thing: what are we looking at on the energy retrofit/house envelope performance (air sealing, insulation) front?  is that on the table as part of the heat pump install, off the table, or already as tightened up as you're willing to go?

@periblepsis -- sorry to ask another question, but what sort of GPM is the well capable of flowing on its own?

@ThreePhaseEel Triple-pane windows, except skylights are double-pane. Exterior walls have been fully opened up, redone, walls are 6" and reinsulated, bugs removed, and resided with cedar. It has made a very noticeable difference. We also replaced the entire pipe from the pumphouse to home and replaced the storage tank and bladder. I'll have to double check on the pump with the installer, but I know it is over-sized (I asked for that.) I knew it would need 150 PSI to get 70 PSI up here. It takes 3 minutes to fill the empty 50 gallon bladder up here. I timed it on final installation.

@periblepsis -- sidenote: what size is the pipe from the well to the house?

Notwithstanding my answer (which I will leave up for now as I think it still has useful information), pretty much anything coming from Harper or ThreePhaseEel should be considered very highly. That being said, Harper - how is it that a ranch panel doesn't count as a main when it has a bunch of branch breakers in it?

Also, if you do go with a ranch panel and move the other 5 rule-of-6 breakers (i.e., except for the 1 controlling the lower section of your current main panel) to it, then you can (if desired) replace that existing "main" (arguably now subpanel) with a new larger "main" (make it the same type and you can reuse breakers) and the overall process will be a bit easier.

@manasshekatz Ranch panel not being main -> 230.82 list of things allowed prior to main breaker.  If you squint real hard, an EVEMS might be allowed.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact As long as the outside "emergency disconnect - not a service disconnect" provides single circuit breaker functionality at service size, I have no quarrel with the "Service Disconnect" remaining 6 hand throws and potentially summing to more than the service size.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica My issue isn't with the Rule of 6, it is that if you stick in a ranch panel as a service disconnect I don't see how it isn't also the main panel because it has more than just a single breaker as disconnect - it has several other breakers that could be used as branch circuits.

@ThreePhaseEel We laid down 2.5" ID wirsbo pipe. It was a huge operation since the pumphouse is 1/4 mile away from the home and about 140 feet below it. (We live on a hillside of a 1200' high "hill.") Part of it was just trenched (along with wire to help relocate it of course) and part of it had to be drilled underneath the wall that can be seen from space! As I said, about 150 PSI at the pump gives us about 70 PSI at the home. Sorry about all the delay. Weekend intervened and I hadn't been back here until now.

@periblepsis -- no worries!  how far up the hill is still yours, by the way?

@manassehkatz If some future person installs a non-230.82 load, they will need to relocate the service disconnect and do all related work.  You don't have to blow up your cost today for something that may not ever happen.

@ThreePhaseEel Unsure of Q: Street level/well head is ~650' ASL, home is ~810' ASL, property extends to ~1000' ASL. The hilltop is ~1200' ASL. Just checked - pressure gauge on line between bladder and hybrid heatpump hotwater tank shows 69 PSI. I over-bought the pump and piping (matched 500 PSI capable.) Just wanted to not have to worry. Old line was old black plastic roll-type from 1970. Trees had since pulled up parts of it and I'd had to compression clamp some broken sections earlier. Not good. Now I'm more confident for a while.

@periblepsis -- yeah, was just curious where the property line was relative to the hilltop

@periblepsis -- one more thing: can you get me a photo of the panel breakers that clearly shows all the labeling on them? your existing photos are grainy/lores and I can't make any of the labeling on the breakers (not even their amp ratings) out as a result

@periblepsis -- also, sorry to ask this of you, but do you have an attached garage?

@ThreePhaseEel Yes. The garage is "just barely" attached, corner to corner (source of water damage I had to repair.)

@periblepsis -- can you get me the depth of the well, at least, if you can't get me the HP of the well pump?  Also, can you get us a better photo of the panel's breakers as well as a photo of the nameplate on the existing furnace?

@ThreePhaseEel On Monday I will call our pump service and get the pump details. Keep in mind it operates from a separate, also personal, transformer and it has a separate service entrance panel at the pumphouse building I recently rebuilt. I can get better breaker pictures, too. And the furnace has a cracked heat exchanger, identified 1 yr ago, which is a reason why a son, wife, and grandkids are now using electric space heaters so much now. Heat pump system in plans for next spring. Can photo oil heat panel, though. Power company visit has been formally scheduled, too. Info here helps!!

@periblepsis see my edit about alternative "battery" storage for maintaining water pessure during outages, and a few otger things.

@Harper I've purchased & installed a surgical 316 steel above ground tank (375 gallons.) It has both manual as well as 12 VDC electric pump. Also, while this connects where I'm located downwards towards California and their PG&E service, up here there is a separate pair of large companies. The one serving me is PGE, not PG&E. I'm told they aren't the same thing -- but with corporate shell companies and ownership arrangements I've actually no idea how connected up these two are. And yes, batteries are key to saving wear & tear & wasted fuel.

@Harper The battery system in the Ford F150 Lightning has been designed to run a house (for a short time -- few hours?) as well as to charge back from the house (80 A charger is what comes with the vehicle, I think.) I need a pickup, anyway. So this might be a way to get started with a "generator" + "battery" for the house, while having a utility vehicle in the bargain that I will use regularly. It's an option I'm considering. But other vehicles are coming around, as well. So I'm still checking options. PGE loves the idea -- they want to use the vehicle for temporary power offloading (free.)

@periblepsis Rather than having a local tank at the level of the house and using electricity to deliver water pressure, my proposal if feasible is to put the local tank ABOVE the level of the house, causing gravity to naturally provide the water pressure.  Thus, the water system passively pressurizes simply from the tank being high.  That works in lieu of a battery providing a passive and failsafe water supply (barring leaks).

@Harper That's in the future. I'd already placed a concrete pad about 10' above the home level but also near the homestead for the diesel/jet fuel tanks. So it went there for now. The fuel tanks must be accessible to a delivery truck. We are on a "shelf" on the hillside and for the fuel case itself I'd need to bring in huge equipment, hire a geotech, and put down still more and expensive blacktop. The water tank would not need that. But that's why i built the pad where i did. It was convenience for now to locate the water there. I'm aware of the value, though.

@ThreePhaseEel The well-pump is this one. It's 2 HP, 3-phase. They also bought a split-phase to 3-phase controller board from the same company to go with it, since we didn't already have 3-phase here. I spoke with the PGE engineer today, as well. He will be helping me working out both short-term and long-term plans, looking ahead. We may get 7.2 kV service, it seems. We need a class A1 cabinet system to support it. But that's fine with me.

@ThreePhaseEel Something else I had no idea about, but the conversation today with PGE seem to put it on the table to consider. We have a profoundly autistic daughter with grand mal seizures and she may require certain equipment to survive a seizure event. Especially in the case of what's called a 'status event'. PGE, he says, can consider providing a special line from the substation's critical generator, directly from there to our home, to provide power during full outages. We will be discussing that option as well. May obviate the need for battery systems here. Not sure, yet, though.

What a crazy informative/professional post.
